# How to merge multiple files in different subdirectories in ubuntu? (one file per subdirectory)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, merge

I need a script that goes through all subdirectories (and possibly sub-subdirectories) and merge all files in them into one per direcory.

I know how to do it in one directory:

```
cat * > merged_file
```

But I need one file per directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd $0; cat * > merged_file' '{}' ';'
```

For each directory found, cd into it and run your command.

If you *don't* want to merge files in the current directory, add `-mindepth 1` before `-type d`